# ArrayList<Post> android

Tags: android, arraylist

I use Jsoup to get the tag value of soap content. for example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(getxml);
Elements element1 = doc.select("codeSession");
code_session = element1.text();
```

where getxml = `</soap><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root></soap>`

I want to store each root element detail into an arraylist how can i achieve this. am on this for two hours now.

```
public ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

Comment: where getxml = "</soap><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root></soap>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet should do it.

```
    String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"></soap><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root><root><one></one><two></two><three></three></root></soap>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(); 
    for (Element e : doc.select("root")) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        list.add(e);
    }
```

Output

```
<root>
<one></one>
<two></two>
<three></three>
</root>
<root>
<one></one>
 <two></two>
 <three></three>
</root>
```

Comment: can i access it through index after this. i mean each root will have an index

Comment: Yes. You can get each root through list.get(index).

Comment: thanks and one last question if i want to access value of tag one ? how do i proceed. do you have a tutorial ?

Comment: Use e.getElementsByIndexEquals(0); That returns the 'one' element.